# Excel: How to Sum by Offset or Hlookup or some other function

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to accomplish the following:

Return me the sum of all cells between columns X and Y, where both X and Y are dynamic variables (perhaps using an offset or Hlookup) that can be hard coded.

One case may be: Sum all the values from columns +20 and columns +62 (20 here means 20 columns from reference cell).

Thanks

Comment: `=SUM(OFFSET(A:A,0,5,,5))` or did you want to do this in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
Function GetOffsetSum(BaseRange As Range, ColOffset1 As Long, ColOffset2 As Long)
    Application.Volatile
    x = Application.Sum(BaseRange.Offset(0, ColOffset1))
    y = Application.Sum(BaseRange.Offset(0, ColOffset2))
    GetOffsetSum = x + y
End Function
```

Screenshot below:

[image]

Hope this helps.